# VHDL: Constraining Record with another record

Tags: vhdl, record

Let's assume I have a type of record containing unconstrained elements:

```
  type Axi4s_M2S is record
    Tvalid : std_logic;
    Tdata  : std_logic_vector;
    Tstrb  : std_logic_vector;
    Tkeep  : std_logic_vector;
    Tlast  : std_logic;
    Tid    : std_logic_vector;
    Tdest  : std_logic_vector;
    Tuser  : std_logic_vector;
  end record Axi4s_M2S;
```

Now I implement two signals. "A" is completely constrained. The other one should be constrained using the first one.

```
signal A: Axi4s_M2S(Tdata(7 downto 0)......);
signal B: Axi4s_M2S(--constrain me likewise A);
```

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: I'd look at subtypes of your base type which add constraints, and make A and B the same subtype.

Comment: Note you type marks in the signal subtype indications don't match the type declaration. Otherwise [use the subtype of A](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7N6z3.jpg) (noting record constraints were introduced in -2008 along with the predefined subtype attribute). `signal B: A'subtype;` (It'd have been easier to validate with a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)).(@BrianDrummond - the latest ghdl builds support this.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With code that analyzes:

```vhdl
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

entity rec_constraint is
end entity;

architecture foo of rec_constraint is
    type Axi4s_M2S is record
      Tvalid : std_logic;
      Tdata  : std_logic_vector;
      Tstrb  : std_logic_vector;
      Tkeep  : std_logic_vector;
      Tlast  : std_logic;
      Tid    : std_logic_vector;
      Tdest  : std_logic_vector;
      Tuser  : std_logic_vector;
    end record Axi4s_M2S;
    
    signal A: Axi4s_M2S(Tdata(7 downto 0), Tstrb(3 downto 0), Tkeep(3 downto 0),
              Tid(31 downto 0), Tdest(7 downto 0), Tuser(3 downto 0));
    signal B: A'subtype;
begin
end architecture;
```

VHDL -2008 supports record constraints in object declarations as well as a predefined attribute that returns the subtype of an object. With those the subtype of A can be used in the declaration of B.

Note that the record type declaration didn't match the type of signals A and B in the question nor was the record constraint complete.